# Split the string an get the text

Tags: java

I am having a text as below

```
*~*****|****|**|*|***|***|****|**|null|null|**|***|***|null|71713470|STMS#******
```

using java i need to get the number 71713470 and STMS values from that string. I have tried all the string methods but invain. Could anyone help on this

Comment: so ... use the split method, and take the 15th and 16th elements of the resulting array

Comment: If i split i am getting as individual element not as an whole text. For example   String[] parts = string.split("|");   String part1 = parts[0]; 
String part2 = parts[1];  

System.out.println(parts[2]);

Comment: Hi fabian could you please provide me the regex pattern to get the text of that position

Comment: @Malik since that is what you need, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** Actually technique [fabian's using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38782886/3850595) with `Pattern` and `Matcher` is far more correct and elegant, but code provided there is not returning values required by OP .

---

You can use `String::split(String)`. It takes a regular expression to split, so use it, `[]` means containing one of... so putting `|` inside will match what you want:

```
String s = "*~*****|****|**|*|***|***|****|**|null|null|**|***|***|null|71713470|STMS#******";
s.split("[|]")[14]
```

Will output:

```
71713470
```

And

```
s.split("[|]")[15].split("[#]")[0]
```

Will give you

```
STMS
```

Comment: It is working for 71713470 but for STMS  the content after that is also coming

Comment: use same technique: `s.split("[|]")[15].split("[#]")[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) with groups to get the relevant parts of the string:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\|(\\d+)\\|STMS#(.*)$");

Matcher m = p.matcher("*~*****|****|**|*|***|***|****|**|null|null|**|***|***|null|71713470|STMS#******");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: mmm one doubt.... is not hardcoding `STMS`  avoid any other text output? (i can imagine OP is not having only this string, but many in this weird format), if text are fixed, fix also number, if not a simple `substring` will do the job....

Comment: op want to extract STMS text itself as stated in comments: *but for STMS the content after that is also coming*

Comment: and your code outputs `71713470` and `******` what does not make much sense.....